# TabLayout Items are being Align to the Start vertically by default. How to fix this issue?

Tags: android, xml, material-design, android-tablayout

I have been using the TabLayout in the Fragment and The TabLayout Items are being shown like this in the image

[image]

This is when I have type use this XML code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/black"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tab One"/>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tab Two"/>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tab Three"/>

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When I remove the 'app:tabMode="scrollable"' from the XML the Layout looks like this.
I tried cleaning the Project. Clearing the Cache, Tried installing the .gradle. None of these didn't work.

[image]

Can SomeOne Help out on solving this issue. Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to make different tabs in a fragment?

Comment: No just only one TabLayout. And When I place the TabLayout in the fragment or Activity style layout the tabs are being displayed like this.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a `TabLayout` that works 100%. Try that and you will be fine!
Start with your Main `Fragment` here `PotatoFragment`, that will contain 2 `fragments` (`AppleFragment` and `BananaFragment`)as tabs later:

```
public class PotatoFragment extends Fragment {



    public PotatoFragment() {
    }

    private AppleFragment appleFragment;
    private BananaFragment bananaFragment;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_potato, container, false);



        TabLayout tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout_potato);
        ViewPager viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager_potato);

        appleFragment = new AppleFragment();
        bananaFragment = new BananaFragment();

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), 0);
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(appleFragment,"");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(bananaFragment,"");
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.apple);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.banana);

        return view;
    }

    private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<String> fragmentTitle = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int behavior) {
            super(fm, behavior);
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            fragments.add(fragment);
            fragmentTitle.add(title);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return fragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragments.size();
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return fragmentTitle.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Write an it's `XML` file, here the `fragment_potato.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="PotatoFragment"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#35c1f1">
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout_potato"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#35c1f1"/>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager_potato"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now you just need to create 2 empty `Fragments`, called `AppleFragment` and `BananaFragment`. Here you go. You created one `Fragment` that holds 2 Tab `Fragments`. If you fill up the 2 `Fragments` with content, the Main `Fragment` will hide behind and normally stays empty. Cheers Buddy! I think the question is answered by now :) Give it a shot.

Comment: I am using the viepager2 and tabMediator to connect the tabs and pages and still I am getting the same result.

Comment: Normaly you shouldn't get this error if you rebuild it from scratch... I can't see your other code. But I use a TabLayout on my own app. And everything works fine.

Comment: I updated my answer. I created an example for you. That will work 100% (tried on my own). You get your Tabs with the suggested documentation way. Try it! :)